# Twitter API to find two direction following users

Tags: twitter

Is there a quick way to find a list of users who I followed and they also followed me back? Just wanted to get a list more like "friend" aspect.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried taking the people who you follow and subtracting the people who follow you?

Comment: yeah I've tried that. But just want to know if there is a easier way or exists gem or plugin. Thanks